# How to send image from local folder with telegram bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api, telegraf.js

I'm making telegram bot on nodeJs and I failed trying to find information on how to send local photo with bot. Official documentation says "upload a new photo using multipart/form-data". What does that mean ? If you now a better way of sending photos (maybe putting folder on server and make requests to it) you can answer too !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method [`sendPhoto`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto) and pass the photo's url in the `photo` parameter. Otherwise you can send the photo to the bot, get the photo's `file_id` and put it in the `photo` parameter.

Simple request:

```
{
  "chat_id": 777000,
  "photo": "https://www.google.com/logo.png",
}
```

or

```
{
  "chat_id": 777000,
  "photo": "AAMCBAADGQEAAQNWw17pM7Z_kM_nftmLt5F49qkR",
}
```

Comment: Can I just put local link like "/sources/img/20-2.jpg" ?

Comment: No, you can't. The image must be accessibile from the internet so Telegram's servers can download it